# Living in Germany, working remotely for a Swiss Company- taxes?

Tags: income-tax, european-union

I am an EU citizen, living in Germany.
I was offer the possibility to work 100% remotely for a company in Switzerland, a "classic" employment contract. I will not be an Grenzgänger. I understood that I need to pay taxes were I work, so in Germany.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to pay remote work tax contributions or any other tax in Swiss system?
2. Who is paying the income taxes and the social security in Germany, me or the Swiss employer?
3. I have a health insurance in Germany. I assume that I don't need a Swiss health insurance due to remote work. Am I right?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the tax systems at play to provide an answer, but before you seek external advice, does your new company offer any form of tax advice, or perhaps have some type of FAQ you could read? In many cases, if a company does this somewhat frequently, they will have such services set up as a courtesy for their employees (at least in part because it's a bit of CYA for their own tax obligations, as well).

Comment: Addendum - if your question is relevant because you want to understand your after-tax pay of a pending job offer, that is something you should mention to the potential employer, as they may be motivated to be very helpful to you with getting the correct answer.

Comment: What is stated as your place of work? Germany or Switzerland?

Comment: For point 3, you don't need health insurance since you don't live in Switzerland and you have health insurance in Germany. Source: https://www.ch.ch/en/health-insurance-foreigners/